# Spinning UP pyglet.gl.ContextException: Could not create GL context over ssh

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-api

I tried to run spinningup code on ubuntu server and render a locally stored video, but it failed with this error.

https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/user/installation.html

```
python -m spinup.run ppo --hid "[32,32]" --env LunarLander-v2 --exp_name installtest --gamma 0.999
```

it seems working well

```
python -m spinup.run test_policy data/installtest/installtest_s0
```

but it doesn't work well with following errors

```
/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/logger.py:30: UserWarning: WARN: Box bound precision lowered by casting to float32
  warnings.warn(colorize('%s: %s'%('WARN', msg % args), 'yellow'))
Logging data to /tmp/experiments/1672370368/progress.txt
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/spinningup/spinup/utils/test_policy.py", line 153, in <module>
    run_policy(env, get_action, args.len, args.episodes, not(args.norender))
  File "/workspace/spinningup/spinup/utils/test_policy.py", line 121, in run_policy
    env.render()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/core.py", line 235, in render
    return self.env.render(mode, **kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/box2d/lunar_lander.py", line 320, in render
    from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl import *
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 244, in <module>
    import pyglet.window
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1880, in <module>
    gl._create_shadow_window()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 220, in _create_shadow_window
    _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 591, in __init__
    context = config.create_context(gl.current_context)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py", line 206, in create_context
    return XlibContext13(self, share)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py", line 314, in __init__
    super(XlibContext13, self).__init__(config, share)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/gl/xlib.py", line 218, in __init__
    raise gl.ContextException('Could not create GL context')
pyglet.gl.ContextException: Could not create GL context
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/workspace/spinningup/spinup/run.py", line 243, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(args, env=os.environ)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/root/anaconda3/envs/spinningup/bin/python', '/workspace/spinningup/spinup/utils/test_policy.py', 'data/installtest/installtest_s0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

libGL errors are fixed with

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

But other than that, most errors still occur.

I'm using SSH in ubuntu-based docker server (not localhost)

with SSH -X command and vscode ssh extension in local MAC OS (not M1 or M2)

both is working fine with x-apps like xeyes, xclock but that errors still occur

using xvfb is the best solutions? i don't know exactly what to use and how to use.

i tried in local server but tensorflow doesn't work well, so i want to fix that error in server